# R capture everything from pattern until pattern

Tags: regex, r, capture

I am trying to extract a substring in between the two patterns `BB` and `</p>`:

```
require("stringr")
str = "<notes>\n  <p>AA:</p>\n   <p>BB: word, otherword</p>\n    <p>Number:</p>\n    <p>Level: 1</p>\n"
str_extract(str, "BB.*?:</p>")
```

The extracted substring should be "word, otherword", but I capture too much:

```
  [1] "BB: word, otherword</p>\n    <p>Number:</p>"
```

Comment: `.*` is greedy. It'll capture until the last occurrence of `</p>`

Comment: @Arun Actually, `.*` is greedy, but `.*?` is not. I think that's a mispaced colon but the problem is still not completely solved.

Comment: oops, dint see the `?`, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
> gsub(".*BB: (.*?)</p>.*$", "\\1", str)
# [1] "word, otherword"
```

Comment: The gsub works fine for my application and then I do not need the stringr package. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for Perl regular expressions. Namely, lookahead and lookbehind references. In `stringr` you can wrap the regex in a `perl` function like so:

```
str_extract(str, perl("(?<=BB: ).*?(?=</p>)"))
[1] "word, otherword"
```

You can also do this with base:

```
regmatches(str, regexpr(perl("(?<=BB: ).*?(?=</p>)"), str, perl=TRUE))
[1] "word, otherword"
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it is better to use base